# Merge every two lines after the pattern until next pattern

Tags: awk, sed

File.txt

```
String1?
word1
word2
word3
word4

String2?
word5
word6
word7
word8
```

Desired Output:

```
String1?
word1 | word2
word3 | word4

String2?
word5 | word6
word7 | word8
```

Only pattern is Lines with `/?$/`
I tried:

```bsh
sed '/\?$/{n;:l N;/\?$/b; :a; N; $!b a; s/\n\s\{1,\}/ | /g; bl}'
```

but it didn't work.
My current working solution:

```bsh
sed '/\?$/{:a;N;/\n....-..-.. /!s/\n/ - /;ta;P;D}' | sed 's/^[- ]*//g;s/[ -]*$//g'
```

... but it's a work-around and is extremely slow.
Can anyone help with a single one liner without pipes and is a fast solution?

If an empty line doesn't exist, as in pattern `,$\|^$`, and if ^$ is not there and is having another line with ?$, then how can we hold the buffer from ?$ to first non-greedy ?$ pattern and then print all lines except the last line and merge the last line with the next pattern buffer for search?

Comment: The escaped question mark `/\?/` or plus `/\+/` is a special character - a quantifier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GNU sed only.
If all lines of the block have 2 columns exactly (your case):

```
sed '/?$\|^$/b;N;s/\n/ | /' File.txt
```

If odd-numbered content is possible (universal way):

```
sed '/?$\|^$/b;N;/\n$/!s/\n/ | /' File.txt
```

Comment: Note that it assumes GNU `sed`. There's no alternation operator in POSIX BRE, you can't have any other command after the `b` one on the same line. POSIXly: `sed -e '/^\(.*?\)\{0,1\}$/b' -e '$!N;s/\n/ | /'`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas There exists other `sed` implementations that allows `b` with no label occurring before other commands in a single `-e` expression.

Comment: @they, yes, though that would be the ones that were designed to mimic the GNU implementation like busybox. It's true these days, a lot of the GNUism have permeated into other implementations. Note that it's not only for `b` with no label. `b a;b` branches to the `a;b` label in historical implementations. That even used to be required by POSIX (I was the one  asking for that requirement to be relaxed).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, thanks. Can you check this? `sed -e '/?$\|^$/b' -e 'N;/\n$/!s/\n/ | /'` The option you suggested does not work with odd content.

Comment: The solution I gave above was a POSIX translation of your first solution. There's no `\|` in POSIX `sed`. `\{0,1\}` is the POSIX BRE equivalent of POSIX ERE `?` (or GNU BRE `\?`). In POSIX `sed` (including GNU `sed` when POSIXLY_CORRECT is in the environment), calling `N` on the last line of input discard the current pattern space.

Comment: Thaks. Just a question if empty line doesnt exist as in pattern ,$\|^$. If ^$ is not there and is having another line with ?$. How can we hold bufffer from ?$ to first non greedy ?$ pattern and then print all lines except last line and merge the last line with next pattern buffer for search

Comment: @TathastuPandya, `sed '/?$/n;N;/?\n\|?$/!s/\n/ | /'`

Comment: @TathastuPandya, can reduce `sed '/?$/n;N;/?$/M!s/\n/ | /'`

Answer (score 4):

```bsh
$ sed '/?$/,/^$/ { //b; N; y/\n/|/; }' file
String1?
word1|word2
word3|word4

String2?
word5|word6
word7|word8
```

For lines in the range `/?$/,/^$/`, i.e., from a line with a `?` at the end to an empty line:

- If the current line is either the first or last in the range, nothing is done (`//b`; "branch to the end of the script if the most recently matched regular expression (in this cycle) matches").
- Otherwise, append the next line of input to the buffer (`N`), and replace the inserted newline character with a `|` character.  If you want spacing around the pipe, use `s/\n/ | /` instead of `y/\n/|/`.

POSIX-ly:

```bsh
sed -e '/?$/,/^$/ { //b' -e N -e 'y/\n/|/' -e '}' file
```

or, with a separate script file, here provided via a here-document,

```bsh
sed -f /dev/stdin file <<'END_SED'
/?$/,/^$/ {
    // b
    N
    y/\n/|/
}
END_SED
```

---

The same sort of thing with `awk`,

```bsh
awk -v OFS='|' '
    /\?$/,length == 0 {
        if ( !/\?$/ && length != 0) {
            getline n
            print $0, n
        } else print
    }' file
```

The above code could also have used `/^$/` in place of `length == 0`, and where you could use `OFS=' | '` in place of `OFS='|'` if you want spaces around the pipe delimiters in the output.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your input is blocks of text separated by blank lines as shown in your sample input, then using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ awk -v RS= -F'\n' -v OFS=' | ' '{print $1; for (i=2; i<NF; i+=2) print $i, $(i+1); print ""}' file
String1?
word1 | word2
word3 | word4

String2?
word5 | word6
word7 | word8
```

Answer (score 0):

Using awk we may try the following:

```
awk -v OFS=' | ' '
!NF ||  /\?$/ {k=0}
NF  && !/\?$/ {k++}
{ORS = k%2 ? OFS : RS}1
' file
```

---

Output:-

```
String1?
word1 | word2
word3 | word4

String2?
word5 | word6
word7 | word8
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl in paragraph mode (-00) we can do as follows:-

```
perl -aF'\n' -nls -00e '
  print shift @F;
  print splice(@F,0,2) while @F>1;
  print @F if !eof;
' -- -,=" | " file
```

---

Using GNU sed in its extended regex mode (-E) to simplify regex writing:

```
sed -E '
  /./{H;$!d;}
  x;$!G;s///
  s/([^\n]*\n){2}/&|/g
  s/\n\|/ | /g
' file
```